# SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module when testing using jest and react-testing-library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am always getting this error whenever trying to test my file using `jest` and `react-testing-library`

error --

```
    Details:

    /Users/user/dev/system-wheels/src/Constants/index.js:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,jest){import { MAP_API_KEY } from "../config.local";
                                                                                      ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

      at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (node_modules/jest-cli/node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1517:14)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/graceful-fs/polyfills.js:1:99)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        0.777 s
Ran all test suites matching /Loginpage.test.js/i.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

Here is my package.json-

```
{
  "name": "system-wheels",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@firebase/app": "^0.6.29",
    "@firebase/messaging": "^0.7.15",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.0.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.2.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-places-autocomplete": "^7.3.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.2",
    "react-router": "^5.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "react-window": "^1.8.6",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "reselect": "^4.0.0",
    "storage": "file:./src/Packages/Storage/",
    "styled-components": "^5.2.1",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "bash ./scripts/init.sh && react-scripts start",
    "build": "bash ./scripts/init.sh && react-scripts build",
    "test": "bash ./scripts/init.sh && react-scripts test --transformIgnorePatterns \"node_modules/(?!@toolz/allow-react)/\" --env=jsdom",
    "test2": " jest",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "alias": {
    "modules": "src/Modules/",
    "components": "src/Common/Components/",
    "hooks": "src/Hooks/",
    "helper": "src/Helper/",
    "common": "src/Common/",
    "globalStyles": "src/GlobalStyles/",
    "constants": "src/Constants/",
    "assets": "src/Assets/",
    "context": "src/Context/",
    "route": "src/Routes/"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs": "^7.15.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.15.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.15.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.14.5",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.15.3",
    "babel-jest": "^27.1.0",
    "jest": "^27.1.0",
    "ts-jest": "^27.0.5"
  }
}
```

Here is my - babel.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    ["@babel/preset-env", { targets: { node: "current" } }],
    "@babel/preset-react",
  ],
};
```

Here is my - jest.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  preset: "ts-jest",
  testEnvironment: "jest-environment-jsdom",
  transform: {
    "^.+\\.(ts|tsx)?$": "ts-jest",
    "^.+\\.(js|jsx)?$": "babel-jest",
  },
  moduleNameMapper: {
    "^constants$": "<rootDir>/src/Constants/",
    "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$":
      "<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js",
    "\\.(css|less)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/styleMock.js",
    "^modules(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/Modules/",
    "^helper$": "<rootDir>/src/helper/",
    "^context$": "<rootDir>/src/Context/",
    "^route(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/Routes/",
    "^assets(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/Assets/",
    "^globalStyles(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/GlobalStyles/",
    "^common(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/Common/",
    "^hooks(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/Hooks/",
    "^components(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/Common/Components/",
  },
};
```

Here is the unit test

```
import "@testing-library/jest-dom";

import React from "react";
import { render, fireEvent, waitFor, screen } from "@testing-library/react";

import LoginPage from "../Views/LoginPage";


describe("Login page testing", () => {
  let wrapper;
  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = render(<LoginPage />);
  });

  test("should contain input fields", () => {
    screen.getByLabelText("Your Email");
    screen.getByLabelText("Password");
  });
});
```

Here is the LoginPage component

```
import React, { useState, useCallback } from "react";
import { bindActionCreators } from "redux";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

import Form from "./Form";

import { loginUser, updateLoginType } from "../../../Common/ActionCreators";
import useAlert from "../../../Hooks/useAlert";

import Path from "../../../Routes/Path";
import BACK_IMAGE from "../assets/background.png";
import SOFTWARE_IMAGE from "assets/OMS.svg";

import { ViewPortContainer, BackgroundImage, SoftwareLogo } from "../styles";

const { companySelection } = Path.authorized;

const LoginPage = ({ loginUser, history, updateLoginType }) => {
  const [inProgress, updateProgress] = useState(false);
  const { showAlert } = useAlert();

  const navigateToCompanySelectionPage = () => {
    history.replace(companySelection.view.path);
  };

  const onFormSubmit = useCallback(async (values, resetForm) => {
    const { login_email, login_password, login_loginAs } = values;
    try {
      updateProgress(true);
      updateLoginType({ isLoggedInAsAdmin: Boolean(login_loginAs) });
      await loginUser({
        emailOrMobile: login_email.toLowerCase(),
        password: login_password,
        isAdmin: Boolean(login_loginAs),
      });
      updateProgress(false);
      navigateToCompanySelectionPage();
    } catch (err) {
      updateProgress(false);
      showAlert({ message: err[0], type: "error" });
    }
  }, []);
  return (
    <ViewPortContainer>
      <SoftwareLogo src={SOFTWARE_IMAGE} />
      <BackgroundImage src={BACK_IMAGE} />
      <Form onFormSubmit={onFormSubmit} inProgress={inProgress} />
    </ViewPortContainer>
  );
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) =>
  bindActionCreators(
    {
      loginUser,
      updateLoginType,
    },
    dispatch
  );

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(LoginPage);
```

I am stuck at this problem for days, please Help

Comment: where the unit test code ?

Comment: I have added the unit test, please have a look

Comment: Why are you creating `d = document.createElement` in a unit test ? Also, where is the code for `LoginPage` component ?> Please make sure you provide all details so we can assist better.

Comment: i have updated the code, please have a look